# How to deny access to url, if it contains the string ".html" ( using htaccess, I want to get a 404 )

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an external javascript, which generates the consent form for using cookies and data protection etc. The script is loaded to costumers pages from my server and checks the availabitity of a URL for the data protection infos. For better understanding here I only show the javascript functions, which are directly relevant to the question:

```
var ping_url = function (url) {
    var request = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    request.open('HEAD', url, true);
    request.send();
    if (request.status === "404") return false;
    else return true;
};

var find_page = function () {
    var pages = [];
        pages.push('./datenschutz.html'); // I want a 404 for this
        pages.push('./service/datenschutz.html'); // I want a 404 for this
        pages.push('./service/datenschutz'); // I want a 200 for this
    var i, s, len = pages.length;
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        if (i in pages) {
            s = pages[i];
            if (ping_url(s)) return s;
        }
    }
    return window.location.href + '#404'; //fallback to actual page
};
```

This works good, as long as URLs with a trailing ".html" are used.
Now I am working on a customers website, where URLs do not contain ".html", but only "/user/23456" or "/content/here-is-the-friendly-readable-url".

The question is, how do I need to modify the htaccess file in this way, that mod_rewrite handles all other parameters but sends a 404, if the URL contains or ends with the string ".html"?

Here's the actual unmodified .htaccess file, which until now works perfect.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?de/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=1&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?en/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=2&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?fr/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=3&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?it/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=4&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?es/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=5&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?hu/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=6&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^ index.php?page_id=1&lang=1&show_lang_select=1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?lang=1&page_id=1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    #redirect .html files to /404
    RewriteCond ℅{THE_REQUEST} \.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
    #handle extension less html files
    RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?de/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=1&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?en/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=2&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?fr/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=3&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?it/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=4&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?es/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=5&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*/)?hu/([^.]*)(.[^\?]*)? index.php?lang=6&rewrite_values=$2&%1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^ index.php?page_id=1&lang=1&show_lang_select=1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?lang=1&page_id=1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One plus for this. The code works, after I changed your ℅-character to %. Is it a typo or does it have a deeper meaning ?

Comment: Even if the htaccess now is doing what it should, my javascript doesn't deliver the desired result :-(